# mongodb - not able to access data by copying /data/db files to new machine

Tags: mongodb, mongorestore

I am a newbie to mongodb and I need a help on mongodb data restoration.

Earlier, I had been running mongo instance (2.6.4) in my windows 7 64bit and had different dbs and collections in it.
currently I bought a laptop with windows 8 64 bit.

Now I want to use the same db in windows 8. I tried copying all data files (/data/db) from old laptop to  new one and tried starting the mongod instance.

(Note: I am using same version of mongodb in my old and new laptop)

It did not start properly and getting below error. kindly help to resolve.

Thanks in Advance

> C:\Users\vijaidhas>mongod --dbpath E:\Mongo\data\db
>
> 2015-01-11T20:54:36.787+0530 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=5420 port=27017 dbpath=E:\Mongo\data\db 64-bit host=vinayag
>
> 2015-01-11T20:54:36.788+0530 [initandlisten] targetMinOS: Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2
>
> 2015-01-11T20:54:36.788+0530 [initandlisten] db version v2.6.4
>
> 2015-01-11T20:54:36.789+0530 [initandlisten] build info: windows sys.getwindowsversion(major=6, minor=1, build=7601, platform=2, service_pack='Service Pack 1') BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
>
> 2015-01-11T20:54:36.789+0530 [initandlisten] allocator: system
>
> 2015-01-11T20:54:36.789+0530 [initandlisten] options: { storage: { dbPath: "E:\Mongo\data\db" } }
>
> 2015-01-11T20:54:36.843+0530 [initandlisten] journal dir=E:\Mongo\data\db\journal
>
> 2015-01-11T20:54:36.844+0530 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
>
> 2015-01-11T20:54:36.945+0530 [initandlisten] **blog Assertion failure isOk() D:\data\mci\shell\src\src\mongo/db/storage/extent.h 80**
>
> 2015-01-11T20:54:37.460+0530 [initandlisten] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\util\stacktrace.cpp(169)                   mongo::printStackTrace+0x43
>
> 2015-01-11T20:54:37.460+0530 [initandlisten] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\util\log.cpp(127)                          mongo::logContext+0x9c
>
> 2015-01-11T20:54:37.461+0530 [initandlisten] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\util\assert_util.cpp(115)                  mongo::verifyFailed+0x14a
>
> 2015-01-11T20:54:37.461+0530 [initandlisten] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\storage\extent_manager.cpp(229)         mongo::ExtentManager::getExtent+0x66
>
> 2015-01-11T20:54:37.461+0530 [initandlisten] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\structure\collection_iterator.cpp(58)   mongo::FlatIterator::FlatIterator+0x93
>
> 2015-01-11T20:54:37.461+0530 [initandlisten] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\catalog\collection.cpp(137)             mongo::Collection::getIterator+0xad
>
> 2015-01-11T20:54:37.461+0530 [initandlisten] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\exec\collection_scan.cpp(92)            mongo::CollectionScan::work+0xc7
>
> 2015-01-11T20:54:37.461+0530 [initandlisten] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\query\plan_executor.cpp(91)             mongo::PlanExecutor::getNext+0x16b
>
> 2015-01-11T20:54:37.461+0530 [initandlisten] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\catalog\database.cpp(325)               mongo::Database::clearTmpCollections+0x12d
>
> 2015-01-11T20:54:37.462+0530 [initandlisten] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\db.cpp(383)                             mongo::repairDatabasesAndCheckVersion+0x2b9
>
> 2015-01-11T20:54:37.462+0530 [initandlisten] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\db.cpp(734)                             mongo::_initAndListen+0xae1
>
> 2015-01-11T20:54:37.462+0530 [initandlisten] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\db.cpp(781)                             mongo::initAndListen+0x27
>
> 2015-01-11T20:54:37.462+0530 [initandlisten] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\db.cpp(1019)                            mongoDbMain+0x255
>
> 2015-01-11T20:54:37.462+0530 [initandlisten] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\db.cpp(824)                             wmain+0x35
>
> 2015-01-11T20:54:37.462+0530 [initandlisten] mongod.exe    f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_64_amd64\crt\src\crt0.c(278)  __tmainCRTStartup+0x13b
>
> 2015-01-11T20:54:37.462+0530 [initandlisten] KERNEL32.DLL                                                           BaseThreadInitThunk+0xd
>
> 2015-01-11T20:54:37.462+0530 [initandlisten] blog
>
> 2015-01-11T20:54:37.463+0530 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 0 assertion D:\data\mci\shell\src\src\mongo/db/storage/extent.h:80, terminating
>
> 2015-01-11T20:54:37.463+0530 [initandlisten] dbexit:
>
> 2015-01-11T20:54:37.463+0530 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
>
> 2015-01-11T20:54:37.463+0530 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
>
> 2015-01-11T20:54:37.463+0530 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
>
> 2015-01-11T20:54:37.463+0530 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
>
> 2015-01-11T20:54:37.463+0530 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
>
> 2015-01-11T20:54:37.463+0530 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
>
> 2015-01-11T20:54:37.486+0530 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
>
> 2015-01-11T20:54:37.489+0530 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
>
> 2015-01-11T20:54:37.489+0530 [initandlisten] journalCleanup...
>
> 2015-01-11T20:54:37.489+0530 [initandlisten] removeJournalFiles
>
> 2015-01-11T20:54:37.504+0530 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
>
> 2015-01-11T20:54:37.504+0530 [initandlisten] dbexit: really exiting now

Answer (score 4):

You should use the [`mongodump`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongodump/) and [`mongorestore`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/) commands to create and restore data from and to mongodb.

I don't know technically why mongodb can't read the files that were in the data directories, but even if it had appeared to work, it would be much safer to do data migration the official way.